# Naming attributes and methods in Qt

Tags: qt, properties, naming-conventions

I'd like to have this:

```
class Test {
  private:
    int a;

  public:
    int a();
    int setA(int val);
}
```

It seems to me that the Qt libraray does this all the time.
But I get a "declaration blabla" compiler error. Why is that?
Do I really have to name the method **getA()**?

I've even tried with Q_PROPERTY:

```
class Test : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int a READ a WRITE setA)

  public:
    int a(){return a}
    int setA(int val){a=val;}
}
```

This also does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt itself, the data members are usually in a Private class (the [Pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl)), so it's not an issue there.
If you don't use Pimpl (which is a bit tedious and only really necessary if you have to guarantee binary compatibility, or have a very large project where reducing includes has a significant enough effect), the most common way is to prepend the member with a prefix, e.g. m_:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(int a READ a WRITE setA)

public:
    void setA( int a ) { m_a = a; }
    int a() const { return m_a; }

private:
    int m_a;
```

Another advantage is also that member and local variables are always easy to tell from each other.

Alternatives:

- Access the variable via `this->a` (more tedious than m_a)
- Use getA() (makes ugly API, IMHO, but of course depends on your API style - if everything else uses get*, one should just follow suit)